# Transfer Django 2D list to Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, django, list, django-views

Views.py

```
op=[[19.076, 72.87], [28.557166, 77.163675]]
    op=simplejson.dumps(op)
    context={'coord':op}
    return render(request, 'output.html' , context)
```

Template.html

```
var a = "{{coord |safe}}";
```

Still, the 'a' variable comes out to be string type and not array type.How to make it a 2d array.

Comment: Try removing the double quotation marks i.e. `var a = {{coord |safe}};`

Comment: Omg thanks such a big oversight on my part! It worked

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing the double quotation marks

```
var a = {{coord |safe}};
```